# Convert a string that contains numbers to a vector of numbers

Tags: r, string, vector

I want to convert a string that contains numbers into a vector with the same numbers. What I  have done so far:

```
x <- "1234567890"
split <- unlist(strsplit(x,split = NULL))
split
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0"
str(split)
chr [1:10] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "0"
```

So my split variable is still a string. I would like to end up with a vector:

```
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
str(vector)
num [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: You convert to numeric with `as.numeric(split)`

Comment: Hmm, kinda seems like this would have been a dupe like 10 years ago.

Comment: @RichScriven I just saw it, you are right, but I hadn't seen it.. It's exactly the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.numeric` like

```
as.numeric(split)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

or

```
as.integer(split)
```

---

If we are using `python`, the option would be to wrap with `list` which returns a `list` of `character`

```
list('123456')
#['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

and for conversion to integer

```
list(map(int, '123456'))    
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the addition of a python approach. I am trying to alternate between the two (beginner) an I find myself often confused.

Answer (score 5):

Use `as.numeric` like this:

```
x <- "1234567890"
split <- unlist(strsplit(x,split = NULL))
as.numeric(split)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do it in one line

```
x <- "1234567890"
as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]])
```

**Result**

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A more esoteric solution...

```
as.integer(charToRaw("1234567890"))-48

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```